# XML for a EditText background

Tags: android, styles, shapes

I have been struggling a little on being able to style my `EditText` like what is in the screenshot. Any tips on how to do it right.

The things I would want the style to do.

```
- The bottom margin / line should stay at the bottom regardless of the 
  height of the EditText
- The height of the EditText should not be hardcoded
- How to place the arrow to the right of the EditText
```

I looked into `<layer-list>` to set the shapes right.

Please see the attachment to know what I am trying to accomplish.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: and what is your <layer-list> like?

Answer (score 1):

First of all Use `TextInputLayout` with `EditText` that will make bottom underline   `android:drawableRight` for `EditText`

like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/til_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/your_drawable_name"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

For more details on [design-library](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)

Comment: Yes, I was hoping to know what I should keep in my drawable.

Comment: image  file of your right side of `EditText` arrow icon